# ArcGIS Server 10 and SQL Server 2008 R2 permissions and feature services

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I have ArcGIS Server 10 with SP1 and SP2 on windows server 2008 and ArcSDE (from an edn liscense) installed on top of MS SQL Server 2008.

When I make a spatial db connection in ArcCatalog (direct connect) using DB Auth as user sde, then I change the version to dbo.Default instead of the sde.Default and the connection is in place.  When I come back to the connection later and double-click the connection, ArcCatalog doesn't retain the user and password credentials for SQL Server and I am asked with a different looking dialogue (not the normal spatial db connection dialog) to re-enter credentials.  Why would ArcCatalog not retain the info?

And how would this affect creating a feature service if at all?

Also I have the arcgissoc user with SQL Server instance login privileges as windows authentication only (not db authentication at the instance level) how would this affect creating a edit-able feature service?

Comment: that sounds like a timeout in sql server.

Comment: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/dotnet/index.htm#users_roles_sql_server.htm I'll be right back with the 10 version.

Comment: Sounding to me to be a Driver version issue, like your machine trying to do the Direct-Connect is not using the right driver. Did you update your SQL drivers recently?

Comment: Why do you change from SDE.Default  to dbo.Default?

Comment: Are you checking the box in the Connection Properties dialog to save the Username and Password?

Answer (score 2):

[link to connection string parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)
Not sure how to get this into arccatalog dialog though.
[Users and Roles Overview](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Overview_of_setting_up_users_and_roles/00040000002m000000/)

Comment: Anyone have a link that shows esri's preferred way to configure users accounts in sql server?

Comment: Woohoo... very loaded question... the way ESRI Prof services does this; and much of Tech-Marketing versus BPs goes diffenent paths. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002q0000002s000000 points to a high-level doc, but keep in mind that RDBMS-DBAs often prefer things a little different and you can easily start a blood-fued if you can't have them understand why things need to be a certain way.

Comment: @Justin, you have to assign privs on feature classes using ArcCatalog.  That is the only reliable way.  ArcSDE is going to take the most restrictive privs.  The only reliable way that I have seen is to drop all privs on the feature class from the db then add them back using ArcCatalog.